# Angular *ngIf is not working in conjunction with ng-template

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, ng-template

When up to 3 icons I need less space compared to when I have 3 icons or more.

To solve this, I'm using the following code, which combines an ***ngIf** with an **ng-template**.

However, the combination is not working.
You can review the HTML code below:

```html
<div *ngIf="i < 3; then 3Icons else MoreThan3Icons">

    <ng-template #3Icons>
        <div class="col-2 statistic-element-physical" *ngFor="let icon of content; index as i;" [ngClass]="{'offset-1': i === 0 }">
            <div class="circle-physical-3icons"><img src={{icon.IMAGE}} alt="statistics-icon" style="height: 4.25rem;width: 4.25rem;"></div>
            <h3 class="number-gold-physical-3icons">{{icon.HEADLINE}}</h3>
            <p class="text-grey-physical-3Icons">{{icon.TEXT}}</p>
        </div>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #MoreThan3Icons>
        <div class="col-4 statistic-element-physical" *ngFor="let icon of content; index as i;" [ngClass]="{'offset-1': i === 0 }">
            <div class="circle-physical-MoreThan3Icons"><img src={{icon.IMAGE}} alt="statistics-icon" style="height: 4.25rem;width: 4.25rem;"></div>
            <h3 class="number-gold-physical-MoreThan3Icons">{{icon.HEADLINE}}</h3>
            <p class="text-grey-physical-MoreThan3Icons">{{icon.TEXT}}</p>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

Comment: And what's your issue ? You have error ? It alsways show first(or second) template ?

Comment: Yeah I got this: Parser Error: Unexpected token else at column 20 in [i < 3; then 3Icons else MoreThan3Icons] in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<div *ngIf="i < 3; then ThreeIcons; else MoreThanThreeIcons"></div>

    <ng-template #ThreeIcons>
      <div>3</div>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #MoreThanThreeIcons>
      <div>3 More</div>
    </ng-template>
```

we did not use number in template.

Answer (score 2):

Your `ng-template` should be outside of `ngIf`

```html
  <div *ngIf="i < 3; then 3Icons else MoreThan3Icons"></div>

    <ng-template #3Icons>
        <div class="col-2 statistic-element-physical" *ngFor="let icon of content; index as i;" [ngClass]="{'offset-1': i === 0 }">

            <div class="circle-physical-3icons"><img src={{icon.IMAGE}} alt="statistics-icon" style="height: 4.25rem;width: 4.25rem;"></div>
            <h3 class="number-gold-physical-3icons">{{icon.HEADLINE}}</h3>
            <p class="text-grey-physical-3Icons">{{icon.TEXT}}</p>

        </div>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #MoreThan3Icons>
        <div class="col-4 statistic-element-physical" *ngFor="let icon of content; index as i;" [ngClass]="{'offset-1': i === 0 }">

            <div class="circle-physical-MoreThan3Icons"><img src={{icon.IMAGE}} alt="statistics-icon" style="height: 4.25rem;width: 4.25rem;"></div>
            <h3 class="number-gold-physical-MoreThan3Icons">{{icon.HEADLINE}}</h3>
            <p class="text-grey-physical-MoreThan3Icons">{{icon.TEXT}}</p>

        </div>
    </ng-template>
```